# jQuery UI #Accordion load then fadeIN... How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, fadein

I'm using a basic jQuery accordion script (using jquery ui), and I'd like to have the area affect by the script first load then fade in (so there isn't a flashing of the images as they all load without jquery then the accordion folds up). What function do I need to add to the JS below to have fadeIn after load of that script (and #accordion and the images)?

Thanks,
JG

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $("#accordion").accordion( {active: 2} );

 });
 </script>

 <style>
  #accordion {
    margin: 0px 0 0;
    width: 640px;
    min-height: 650px;
    float: left;
  }

  #accordion H2 {
    background: #f8f7f5;
    color: #582802;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
 </style>

 <div id="accordion">
     <h2>Click for Image 1</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <img src="img1.jpg">
     </div>

     <h2>Click for Image 2</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <img src="img2.jpg">
     </div>

     <h2>Click for Image 3</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <img src="img3.jpg">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hide the accordion (display:none) and then fadeIn on document ready.

http://jsfiddle.net/nQ6Uv/3

```
<div id="accordion" style="display:none;">...... </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#accordion").accordion( {active: 2} );  
});
```

Comment: Hi, I want to use this way, but it seems to break the accordion. Can you take another look? I've updated the jsfiddle with some content so you can see. thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, try this one http://jsfiddle.net/nQ6Uv/3/.  Updated the code in the post as well.  fadeIn should occur first, then declare the accordian.

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! It is simple and easy, just like I like it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out the my JsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/thewingser/qM5cD/8/

I believe this is what you wanted. Also I replaced your images with paragraphs just because jsfiddle can't resolve your pictures.

**per request of Lokase**

```
<html>
    <head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = (function(){
try{
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
});
}catch(e){}});
</script>
        <style>
            #accordion {
    margin: 0px 0 0;
    width: 640px;
    min-height: 650px;
    float: left;
  }

  #accordion H2 {
    background: #f8f7f5;
    color: #582802;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
    </script>
<div id="accordion">
     <h2>Click for Image 1</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <p>test</p>
     </div>

     <h2>Click for Image 2</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <p>test</p>
     </div>

     <h2>Click for Image 3</h2>
     <div class="content">
         <p>test</p>
     </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your solution code along with your jsfiddle link.  If jsfiddle ever goes down your solution will be lost to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hopefully that never happens :P but I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

     $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 })
 });

 function li() {
     $(".content").fadeIn(500);
     $("#accordion").accordion({ active: this })
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
 <a onclick="li();"><h2>Click for Image 1</h2></a> 
<div class="content"> 
     <img src="Image/cat.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
 </div>

<a onclick="li();"> <h2>Click for Image 2</h2></a>
 <div class="content">
     <img src="Image/catUblueUeyes.jpg"  width="140px" height="140px">
 </div>

<a onclick="li();"> <h2>Click for Image 3</h2></a>
 <div class="content"  >
     <img src="Image/jquery.jpg"  width="140px" height="140px">
 </div>
```

fixed or percentage assigned to the images to avoid damaging the accordion